# Can't access terms and condition from amdin panel

Tags: admin, layered-navigation, terms-and-conditions

I try to access terms and condition from admin panel but I get the following error

```
Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterableAttributeListInterface in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50
```

how can I debug this kind of errors ? [image]

Answer (score 1):

Run below command in magento root and check once again :

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```